# HttpContext.Current.User returns admin account instead of user account

Tags: asp.net, iis, active-directory, windows-identity

I have two Windows accounts, my regular user-level one, and an Administrator one.  As far as I know, there is no connection between the two in AD, other than my name.  I normally log into my dev machine using the user account.

If I run my website locally using VS/IIS Express, I get the following values (as expected):

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name = "DOMAIN\\jespaillat"
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name = "DOMAIN\\jespaillat"
```

On the deployed site, however, when using both Chrome and IE11, I get the following:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name = "DOMAIN\\admin-jespaillat"
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name = "IIS APPPOOL\\DefaultAppPool"
```

Both browsers automatically send my Windows credentials to the server, and do not prompt for login.  I get the same behavior when running incognito.  I can see in Fiddler that the browser is sending a Kerberos ticket with the request, though the account name is not visible within the base64 string.

So where is it getting the name of the admin account, which I am NOT logged in as? And how are the two accounts even connected?

(Interestingly, Firefox DOES prompt for credentials every time, so I am able to enter the correct value.)

---

Windows Server 2016, IIS 10, .NET 4.7.2 .  Desktop is Windows 7

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Only Windows Authentication is enabled in IIS

Comment: Are you sure Chrome is not running as your admin account (even if you are not logged into Windows with it)?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Chrome is not running as administrator;  the option is not checked on the shortcut.  Besides, I don't get the UAC escalation prompt when I start it.  FWIW, Chrome Sync (the icon in the upper right) is connected to my personal gmail.
Also, I don't use IE at all, I only fired it up to check this error

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be running "as administrator" to be running under your admin account credentials. Use Task Manager to check the credentials it's running with, like [this](https://superuser.com/a/893375/233663). (also, Google Sync can still be connected to your personal account regardless of which Windows account is being used)

Comment: @GabrielLuci Nope.  The only process running on my desktop as admin is TaskManager.  On the server, there are a few processes running as my admin account, but all of them are related to the remote desktop login; w3wp is NOT one of them (it runs under the app pool account)  On a fresh server reboot, without remoting into it, I still get the wrong account.  (Like you, I think it's more likely a client/browser issue, but I just want to put that out there for completeness)

Comment: It's getting it from somewhere. Your accounts aren't "connected". Look for the username anywhere in your code, or look for saved passwords in Chrome.

Comment: @GabrielLuci "somewhere"... yes, that's the issue isn't it?  I completely reset settings and cleared all caches on Chrome, same error.   IE (which has no saved settings since I hadn't used it before yesterday), same error.  Chrome incognito & IE InPrivate, same error. I even just downloaded Opera for the hell of it... same error!

Comment: Open Command Prompt and type `set username`. What do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credential Manager was the culprit.

Turns out that CM had an entry for every remote drive that I've ever used Explorer to connect to (and yes, I had checked the box to "remember my credentials").  Including the drive on the web server.

All of the browsers (except Firefox) were conflating the username/password used to access a file share on a machine, with the username/password to access the website on the same machine.  Once I deleted the CM entry for the web server, it worked.